# A96 development board GPRS C SDK Build environment installation in Windows

Tags: c, powershell, microcontroller

I'm following [this tutorial](https://ai-thinker-open.github.io/GPRS_C_SDK_DOC/en/c-sdk/installation_linux.html) for getting started with AI-Thinker board with the A9G chip, but the compilation seems to fail each time I try `./build.bat app`.

I thought it was a GCC problem, but I have installed GCC and the problem still persists.

Here's the error I get when I run in PowerShell:

```
C:/Users/INYANG/Documents/linux_mint/GPRS_C_SDK_RICX/platform/compilation/cust_rules.mk:8: C:/Users/INYANG/Documents/linux_mint/GPRS_C_SDK_RICX/platform/csdk/memd.def: No such file or directory
............

grep: build\app\app.map: No such file or directory
grep: build\app\app.map: No such file or directory
Missing operand.
Missing operand.
```

Comment: Bat-files have nothing to do with Powershell, and you should probably run that file in the cmd.exe command prompt instead.